# How to rewrite PHP files in a subdirectory with .HTACCESS

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a Subdirecotory in my webroot with some PHP files ( www/services/files.php ).

Current url: `http://example.com/index.php?pageID=services/myservice`

I would like it to be: `http://example.com/services/myservice`

My code:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?pageID=/services$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: current code perhpaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make it appear as two subfolers so I would use this code for that type of URL structure. Using an .* would be too greedy.

This will allow you to use `http://example.com/services/myservice`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?pageID=$1/$2 [L]
```